# После команды iptables -F, iptables-save пропал доступ по SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, iptables

После команды `iptables -F` и `iptables -save`, пропал доступ по `ssh`.
Ось `Ubuntu 16.04.5 server`.

Как востановить `iptables` к прежнему виду? и вернуть доступ?

Comment: если перезапуск машины не помогает, то надо подключиться к консоли и сделать всё что требуется.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , есть физический доступ к машине, что сделать то нужно? =)

Comment: добавить недостающие правила netfilter-а, чтобы нейтрализовать политику drop, установленную для какой-то (или нескольких) цепочки. либо изменить эту (эти) политику на accept.

Comment: @Dmitriy Прмер с моей машины "-A IN_FedoraWorkstation_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT"

Comment: @Hellseher спасибо, вот такое правило и снесли админы , еще мне нужны такие цепочки для 21, 80 ,443 порта, все я разобрался. оформите как ответ, я вам плюсик в карму поставлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оформил в виде скрипта, можно добавлять свои порты.

Учтите, что эти правила будут работать до следующей перезагрузки. 
Убедитесь, что у вас не стоит какого-либо стороннего сетевого экрана, который подгружает или сбрасывает настройки iptables

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

[ "$(id -u)" = "0" ] || { echo "Run as root. Exit."; exit 1; }

PORT_ALLOW=(
    21
    22
    80
    443
)

allow_ipv4_port() {
    local port="$1"

    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport "${port}" -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport "${port}" -j ACCEPT
}

main() {

    for p in ${PORT_ALLOW[@]}; do
        allow_ip4_port "$p"
    done
}

main "$@"
# End of script
```

**Ссылки**

- https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-firewall/blob/master/templates/firewall.bash.j2
- https://wiki.debian.org/DebianFirewall

Comment: Извините, уважаемый. По ссылке на github в скрипте использована любопытная конструкция, к примеру `{% for rule in firewall_additional_rules %}` не могли-бы пояснить как это работает. Ну тоесть зачем и для чего используются фигурные скобки я (наверное) представляю. А вот как это работает в сочетании со знаком процента, да еще и цикл разбитый на такие блоки... Заранее спасибо. PS Если нужно могу оформить вопросом.

Comment: @AndreyKarpov гляньте, что это за репозиторий - Ansible шаблон и плейбук для поднятия фаервола на основе iptables. Строчки, где добавляются правила, я переписал под этот вопрос в виде скрипта. Это формат `jinja2`.